# How to Preview Image in browser when user selects the image from window in asp .net FileUpload

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, image, file-upload

I'm working with asp .net and want to upload user's profile image. I'm using  following line of code to upload image. I want to preview image of user when he selects his image without pressing upload button.

```
    <asp:FileUpload ID="Upload" runat="server" />
```

I found various solutions to upload image but in all solutions there is a separate button that uploads the image. Is there any solution to preview image in browser when  the user selects his image without pressing upload button? just like facebook and gmail etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code snippet.

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="Upload" runat="server"  onchange="ShowPreview(this)"/>

<asp:Image ID="impPrev" runat="server" Height="200px" />
```

---

**Javascript**

```
function ShowPreview(input) {  
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {  
                var ImageDir = new FileReader();  
                ImageDir.onload = function(e) {  
                    //Jquery
                    //$('#impPrev').attr('src', e.target.result);  
                    var image = document.getElementyId("impPrev");
                    image.src = e.target.result;
                }  
                ImageDir.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);  
            }  
        }
```

Comment: just below the fileupload control

Comment: @UsamaAzam you should take the time to look and learn javascript events and event handling and ajax.  You are learning nothing if you are just copying what you think will work.

Answer (score 0):

The image must be uploaded no matter what.  So you can have access to it on the server.   There is a variety of ways to allow uploading without your users explicitly needing to see a upload button.  Drag and drop uploading is a version of submitting the upload form behind the scenes and display the response image.

I would look at javascript events like onclick , onfocus or onchange and handling those events so you can then make an ajax request to your server side code that is responsible for handling the uploading.  Once you have the uploaded image on the server you send the image as your response to your ajax request.  The its nothing more than displaying.  If saving is needed you can then save it to its rightful destination or you can delete it.  Ajax fileuploads